# Is there a way to add a resource file manually?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, resx

At the moment I have only my default resource file, AppResources.resx.
I used to have another one for polish language, but deleted it from the project. Now I want it back. Importing the file doesn't work because Visual Studio during building just copies the content from AppResources.resx to my pl-PL file and overwrites everything. Right clicking the pl-PL file and trying to import the translations is not an option too- nothing is being copied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried 'Add Existing item' to add your resx.pl-PL to the project? Just an idea to try

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by saying "Importing the file doesn't work because Visual Studio during building just copies the content from AppResources.resx to my pl-PL file and overwrites everything." ;)